# Comma separator in Lambda function environment settings using the Serverless Framework

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to add a MongoDB cluster as part of a Serverless deployment, but I can't set the environment variable.

Here is part of the **serverless.yml** file:

```
service: serverless-test

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs4.3
  environment:
    MONGO_URI: "mongodb://mongo-6:27000,mongo-7:27000,mongo-8:27000/db-dev?replicaSet=mongo"
```

How do I pass the MONGO_URI to contain the cluster as a comma separated value?

Any advise is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use commas in Lambda environment variables. This is an AWS limitation and not a Serverless issue.

For example, browse the [AWS console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda) and try to add a environment variable that contains a comma:

[image: environment variable foo,bar]

When you save, you will get the following error:

> 1 validation error detected: Value at 'environment.variables' failed to satisfy constraint: Map value must satisfy constraint: [Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [^,]*]

The error message says that the regex `[^,]*` must be satisfied and what this small regex explicitly says is to **not** (`^`) accept the comma (`,`). Any other char is acceptable.

I don't know why they don't accept the comma and this is not explained in their [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html), but at least their error message shows that it is intentional.

As a workaround, you can replace your commas by another symbol (like `#`) to create the env var and replace it back to comma after reading the variable, or you will need to create multiple env vars to store the endpoints.