# AWS Cloudformation - Convert CommaDelimitedList Parameter to String for passing it as environment variable to Lamda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

How to convert CommaDelimitedList Parameter to String for passing it as environment variable to Lamda Function ?

Below is sample CommaDelimitedList Parameter containing list of AWS regions which I need to pass it as Environment variable to AWS Lambda function in cloud formation template. The reason is when I try to pass it as it is `!Ref ExternalRegions` it gives error when create/update of the stack:

```
Properties validation failed for resource LambdaFunction with message: #/Environment/Variables/EXTERNAL_REGIONS: expected type: String, found: JSONArray

Parameters:
  ExternalRegions:
    Description: CSV delimited account regions 
    Type: CommaDelimitedList

Resources:
    LambdaFunction:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
        Properties:
          Environment:
            Variables:
              EXTERNAL_REGIONS: !Ref ExternalRegions
```

Parameter Template:

```
[{
    "ParameterKey": "ExternalRegions",
    "ParameterValue": "us-east-1,us-west-2,ap-southeast-1"
}]
```

Could you please help, I am looking for a way to cast csv list into string so that I don't have to create another String variable with same values and always bother to keep them in sync during future changes.

Thanks in advace.

### Scrub

Can't use comma in environment variable value in Lambda?

[Comma separator in Lambda function environment settings using the Serverless Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683730/comma-separator-in-lambda-function-environment-settings-using-the-serverless-fra)

If this is the case I would like to know a way where I could convert the comma delimited list parameter to string and replace comma with say alternative delimiter for ex. semi-colon (;) and pass it as lambda function variable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out :)

```
Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
      Properties:
        Environment:
          Variables:
            EXTERNAL_REGIONS: !Join [";", !Ref ExternalRegions]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't the issue you linked is still accurate as I was able to create Environment variables containing `,` in the web console [image: env vars]

My recommendation would be to just changes the Parameter to **Type: String** since it looks like your lambda function will have to handle the `;` delimiter anyway.

Additionally, I'd be wary of using a semicolon as a delimiter in environment variables since it can have [unexpected/unintended side effects...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67505935/4526019) (particularly in a shell)

Comment: Ah that's great to know, thank you for the info, actually I wanted to keep it as CSV instead of String as Policy statement resource section also uses the CSV list as selector, for ex. 
`!Select [3, !Ref ExternalRegions]`